# Google Sheets Script - Copy Rows 4:8 and Paste to Last Row of the Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste

I have a need to create a script that copies Rows 4:8 and then whatever the last row of the sheet is, paste those rows in.

**NOTE** - To keep the file small, the sheet has the majority of the rows deleted on purpose. The last row may not always be the same number, so the script must know which the last row is even if there's no data in it.

**EXAMPLE**

If the last row is 20, upon executing the script (which I'll assign to a button), 5 additional rows will be added (which would have come from rows 4:8), extending the sheet to a total of 25 rows.

There's specific formatting in those rows so it's not as simple as just adding 5 additional rows, they must be copies of rows 4:8.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Copy Lines to Bottom including format

```
function copyrows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg = sh.getRange("4:8");//select line 4 through 8
  const drg = sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 2 , 1);//Select destination range. You only have to specify the upper left corner of the range
  rg.copyTo(drg);
}
```

[copyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,Object))

Demo:

[image]

#### Modified to included row heights

```
function copyrows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg = sh.getRange("4:8");//select line 4 through 8
  let hA = [...Array.from(new Array(rg.getHeight()).keys(),x => sh.getRowHeight(x + 4))]
  let lr = sh.getLastRow();
  const drg = sh.getRange(lr + 2 , 1);//Select destination range. You only have to specify the upper left corner of the range
  rg.copyTo(drg);
  hA.forEach((h,i) => sh.setRowHeight(lr + 1 + i, h ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. The function successfully pastes those rows in, along with the formatting, but does not include the originally sized rows (between rows 4:8 there are different row heights)

When I manually copy & paste rows 4:8 to the new destination, it copies everything perfectly and beautifully. Your solution is super close but looks like we're one step away. Is it possible to modify the code to copy row height as well?

Comment: Wow - you are amazing! Your solution is exactly what I was looking for except for one minor detail. 

When I execute the script, everything works now as intended except the newly created rows are cutting of the shading I have below the last row of the sheet. 

In other words, if I can get the pasted rows to shift down by just 1 row, everything would be absolutely perfect. 

Is there a "+1" I can add somewhere to make that happen?

Comment: I just move drg down one row?

Comment: "I just move drg down one row?"

I don't know what that means. I found an instance of "drg" in the code but wouldn't know how to implement that change. Would you mind providing direction?

Comment: Perhaps this would be more helpful. Here is a sample of the worksheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19KDz5freGdeOfJ9-kfQv9_XE-b7EeUyAUOIO2bHTNxk/edit?usp=sharing

Observe the following:

- The last row of cards I labelled one of them as "LAST" so that you can see the difference
- Execute the "Add" script and observe how it successfully adds the new rows (which is really a single card) but it removes the shadowing of the card above it (LAST) and the spacing is not consistent with the other cards (has an extra row)

If these two issues can be fixed the result would be perfect!

Comment: I already made the change just try it

Comment: Still cutting off the shadow row of the "LAST"  card. I've highlighted it yellow for you to see

Comment: I'm not use to dealing with such elaborate formatting.  If you wish to adjust the code on your own go for it because I'm done.

Comment: I understand, thanks kindly for getting me this far

Answer (score 0):

```
function copyrow_4_8(){
        const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
        //replace the columns number with your acutal needed columns 
        const range = ss.getRange(4,1,5,4);
        const range_value = range.getValues();
        const dest_range = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1,1,range_value.length,range_value[0].length);
        //get grid id for the dest range
        const dest_range_Gid = dest_range.getGridId();
        //copy format to the dest range
        range.copyFormatToRange(dest_range_Gid,1,4,ss.getLastRow()+1,ss.getLastRow()+range_value.length+1);
        //set the values to dest range.
        dest_range.setValues(range_value);
    }
```

1. You need to get the original range and values
2. Then you copy format and the values to the destination range.

Comment: Hey thanks for the contribution. Sorry, I should have added that I'm not familiar with code and how to decipher it. I only know how to copy and paste it into the Apps script page, select it, Run it, and assign it to a button if it works.

So when you state "You need to get the original range and values
Then you copy format and the values to the destination range.", I don't know what that means. Would you kindly elaborate?